# Sphinx `todo` ignoring `todo`s in Python docstrings

Tags: python-sphinx, todo

I'm using Sphinx's `todo` extension but the `todo` shown in my code below is being ignored - any ideas why?  It does "see" `todo`s placed into the `index.rst` file so the `todo` processing is enabled.  Thanks for all suggestions because I'm out of ideas!

```
"""This is a test class definition."""
from typing import TypeVar

TypeTestMe = TypeVar("TypeTestMe", bound="TestMe")

class TestMe(object):
    """Simple object to test sphinx"""
    def __init__(self: TypeTestMe, name: str) -> None:
        """
        Constructor for the object.

        The first line is brief explanation, which may be completed with
        a longer one. For instance to discuss about its methods. The only
        method here is :func:`function1`'s. The main idea is to document
        the class and methods's arguments with

        - **parameters**, **types**, **return** and **return types**::

        :param str: The name of the owner of this object
        :type arg1: string
        :return: None

        .. todo::

        Todo in source code.
        """
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, a whole raft of errors it turns out!

1. The `todo` comments are only picked up from docstrings so don't bother putting them into random comments in-line in your code
2. `todo` is built on top of `autodoc` so if `autodoc` is not documenting your code module, you won't get any `todo`s either; fix-up your autodoc config if this is the error
3. The syntax for a `todo` block is indent sensitive so...

```
.. todo:: This comment will appear
.. todo::
This comment is ignored because of bad indentation and you get a warning
.. todo::
   This is the correct indentation and this todo will appear.
```

4. Finally remember to check that your `todo` config is also correct.

Comment: It is a bit strange to say that `todo` is built on top of autodoc. The `todo` directive can be used in .rst files without involving autodoc. But if you have todos in docstrings, then of course you need to use autodoc to see them in the output.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for that clarification.  I was specifically trying to set them inside source code but it's interesting to know this alternative use is possible.